# Can't discover maven.restlet.com

Tags: maven, nexus, restlet

When i build my project the jars for **org.restlet.jee**, as a dependency for **apache-camel**, are missing.

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.spring:jar:2.2.2 is missing, no dependency information available
```

So i added in Nexus a new proxy repository for *http://maven.restlet.com/*.

After adding there is an error during the discovery process:

> Remote strategy prefix-file on M2Repository(id=maven-releases) detected invalid input, results discarded: Prefix file does not start with expected "## repository-prefixes/2.0" header, refusing to load the file.

Is there any solution how i can use the restlet repository with Nexus?

**Edited:** my pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://xxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://xxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>deployment</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>http://xxx:8081/nexus/</nexusUrl>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: please show pom.xml how you're adding this repo

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix file message has to do with automatic routing.  The site at maven.restlet.com doesn't support this feature. It's nothing to worry about though, see here for an explanation:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/30645946-

Check to make sure the proxy repository you just added is a member of the group repository you've configured maven to use in your settings.xml file.

If that isn't the problem you can get information about this problem by using the technique described here:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21433982

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem recently with restlet repo and proxying it through nexus. The problem is it doesn't accept proxying, you'll get this information by using techniques mentioned by rseddon.

To solve the problem you have to update your proxy repository configuration in nexus by setting **a user agent in the optional http request settings** to something being used by browsers, e.g. Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0.

It should help.